# round much slower than floor/ceil/int in LLVM

Tags: c++, rounding, clang++, floor

I was benchmarking some essential routines by executing cycles such as:

```
float *src, *dst;
for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) dst[i] = round(src[i]);
```

All with AVX2 target, newest CLANG. Interestingly floor(x), ceil(x), int(x)... all seem fast. But round(x) seems exremely slow and looking into disassembly there's some weird spaghetti code instead of the newer SSE or AVX versions. Even when blocking the ability to vectorize the loops by introducing some dependency, round is like 10x slower. For floor etc. the generated code uses vroundss, for round there's the spaghetti code... Any ideas?

Edit: I'm using -ffast-math, -mfpmath=sse, -fno-math-errno, -O3, -std=c++17, -march=core-avx2 -mavx2 -mfma

Comment: How might the [*defined behavior*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) involve 'more work'?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but there are usually many ways to get to the result. Then there's the errno thingy with sqrt etc... So may question is simply if there's something needed to make round fast as other routines.

Comment: For what it's worth, with -ffast-math the generated assembly is the effectively the same for both `round` and `floor`.

Comment: well `round` is going to have to branch, since it can go up or down where all the others just go one direction.  What optimization flags did you use?  How did you time the code?

Comment: @NathanOliver It is not about branching. There is a family of SSE rounding instructions which can do rounding efficiently in hardware, but for some reason it is not used for `round`, but is used for `floor` (unless -ffast-math is turned on). I am also curious why is that. Could be simply a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: That's the thing - I'm using -ffast-math, -mfpmath=sse, -fno-math-errno !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that none of the SSE rounding modes specify the correct rounding for `round`:

> These  functions  round  x  to the nearest integer, but round halfway cases away from zero
>          (regardless of the current rounding direction, see fenv(3)), instead  of  to  the  nearest
>          even integer like rint(3).

If you want faster code, you could try testing `rint` instead of `round`, as that specifies a rounding mode that SSE does support.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that! I just checked that AVX2 version generated this code when manually using _mm256_round_ps(a, 0+8) for rounding, it creates vroundps    ymm1,ymmword ptr [rsi+rdx*4+0C0h],8, which seems working fine.

Comment: The `8` operand specifies round to nearest even -- correct for rint, but not correct for round.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that an expression like `floor(x + 0.5)`, while not having the exact same semantics that `round(x)` does, is a valid substitute in almost all use cases, and I doubt it is anywhere near 10x slower than `floor(x)`.

Comment: That actually sounds reasonably simple, where is the problem then? I mean for extremely high values it may end up going to infinity or something, but that doesn't seem like an important issue :)

Comment: floor(x + 0.5), ceil(x - 0.5) and round(x) differ in the way they handle inputs that have a fractional part of exactly .5. I think for most purposes, it is considered an arbitrary choice that doesn't matter too much either way. For numbers too large to fit in fraction digits in the mantissa, all of these expressions behave the same (they just return x)